# customized save actions in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way do define customized save actions in eclipse? Currently eclipse support only predefined set of actions (i.e. organize imports). I want to add my own save actions (for example - auto generate toString() on save).

Is there such a way?

Thanks

Comment: Just for curiosity, why do you want to generate toString() on save ? It seems more suitable for "Code Templates" or "Templates"

Comment: My use case: If I add a member to a class, I want the toString() to be automatically updated. Ideally - I could "tell" eclipse easily which member to include and which not, but at first - using all member is good enough for me

Comment: In that case, you might want to try out [ToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) in [Apache Common lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). I don't think Eclipse can provide auto-generation in such detailed level.

Comment: ToStringBuilder also requires me to write the member in the code. When I add a new member - I also have to update this also, so this will not fulfill my (humble) need.

Comment: ToStringBuilder provide [reflectionToString](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html#reflectionToString(java.lang.Object)) method, which is exactly what you need.

Comment: Very nice! thanks for that. I there something similar for equals & hashcode?

Comment: Yes. check [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) and [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html), both of them following the rules in Effective Java

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to write your own plugin, in which you'd provide an implementation of [ICleanUp](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/cleanup/package-summary.html).  Write .createFix appropriately to do your code generation.  Then you can activate that as a save action, and Eclipse will call your plugin whenever a Java file is saved.

Comment: All that said, for the specific case of doing toString() I'd go with ToStringBuilder as @rangi-lin pointed out!